# Knockout validation require unknown knockout js file

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-validation

I am using require js and knockout js to develop coredova app, When I am using knockout validation, it does not work , it says  "**Script error for: knockout**". It displays following in inspect element  under Network , www/js/knockout.js 404 Not found, but in js folder there is no knockout.js file, but it require that file, This error comes only when i use knockout.validation in define method.But why it asked this type of knockout js file
I made simple code for demostration, please help me

This is my viewModel

```
define(['knockout-3.2.0','knockout.validation'], function(ko,validation) {

    return function appViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable('Bert').extend({ number: true,minLength: 3, maxLength: 10 });

    };
});
```

this is my require path setup

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jQuery': 'jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.min',
        'knockout-3.2.0': 'ko/knockout-3.2.0',
        'knockout.validation': 'ko/knockout.validation'

    },
    shim: {
        'jQuery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'knockout-3.2.0': {
            exports: 'ko'
        },
        "knockout.validation": {
             exports: 'validation'
         }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knockout and also the Knockout-Validation plugin support both the CommonJS and the AMD module pattern, so there is no need to `shim` them.

You get the error because the Knockout-Validation plugin **explicitly depends a module named `"knockout"`** (see on [GitHub](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/blob/be74432bd978c9c7b536887ce24a614a8ec157e7/Dist/knockout.validation.js#L17-L19)) so to fix it you need to rename your `'knockout-3.2.0'` module to `"knockout"`.

So the fixed require.js config would look like:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jQuery': 'jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.min',
        'knockout': 'ko/knockout-3.2.0',
        'knockout.validation': 'ko/knockout.validation'

    },
    shim: {
        'jQuery': {
            exports: '$'
        }
    }

});
```

And of course in your module you need to use the name `"knockout"`:

```
define(['knockout','knockout.validation'], function(ko, validation) {

    return function appViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable('Bert').extend({ number: true,minLength: 3, maxLength: 10 });

    };
});
```